# How can I find out what is preventing garbage collection of an object?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-express

Some of my objects are not being garbage collected, I need to find out where the references to the object are and what is preventing the garbage collection.

I'm using Visual Studio Express.

Comment: Have you tried the Microsoft CLR profiler first? That has some memory analysis tools that may help: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16273

Comment: Your code is. NB it will only be garbage collected if it can't be reached (nothing else is referencing it) and it's a managed object, and collect is being called.

Comment: I've tried to use CLRProfiler, but it just gives me error messages and doesn't seem to run correctly.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: I'm calling GC.collect just to makes sure it runs.

Comment: @Gerve. No point in doing that unless you know it's unreachable. If this is bog standard object, ie you aren't messing about with unmanaged stuff. Then you need to find everything that's points to the object you think should be unreachable and make sure they are also unreachable before you call collect. This is usually some thimng like orderline doesn't get collected, because it's in a order lines collection which is in an order. ie. until you clear order.orderlines, it will hang about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using [Ants Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) which is a very popular tool. It's fairly easy to use and it attempts to give you a graph illustrating what is holding on to your references. Underneath I believe it does something similar to that which Bond suggested, but it gives a much simpler user experience.

It comes with a free 14 day trial. An example of the instance graph is shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ian, this is a great tool.

Answer (score 3):

you can try the [sos extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for [windbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx)
particularly the dumpheap and heapstat commands

Comment: accurate answer, but not trivial to do for the faint hearted ;p

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest:

1. Analyze your code and debug
2. If you are unable to find the leaking you could try this tool: [Memprofiler](http://memprofiler.com/)